# Calculating Data from Separate Workbook VBA

Tags: vba, excel, statistics

I am trying to put together one main spreadsheet that pulls from over 100 workbooks containing various data. I haven't been able to figure out how to access a closed Workbook in order to calculate the standard deviation from one of the rows.

```
Sub RefreshSourceData()
    Dim sourceFile, fileName As String, path As String
    Dim dispersionRange As Range
    path = "U:\SPACE Info\Meeting Materials\Strategy Files\"
    fileName = "[" & ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, 1).Value & ".xls]"
    sourceFile = "=" & path & fileName
    dispersionRange = "=" & path & fileName & "Account'!R:R"
    Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = sourceFile & "Summary'!$F$2"
    Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = sourceFile & "Summary'!$F$3"
    Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = sourceFile & "Summary'!$B$10"
    Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = sourceFile & "Summary'!$D$10"
    Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = WorksheetFunction.StDev(dispersionRange)
End Sub
```

I have received various errors, right now it is "Object Variable or With Object Variable not set."

I have also tried creating a workbook variable consisting of path & filename, but this hasn't worked either.

Comment: Probably the easiest way to do this would be to use VBA to open each workbook ([`workbooks.open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819(v=office.15).aspx)), do the calculation, close the workbook, and move onto the next one. Your current error is happening because you aren't "setting" `dispersionRange`.

Answer (score 0):

These are some ***best effort*** suggestions, since I can't test everything (I don't have your data).

For your immediate error, I think you intended `dispersionRange` to be a `String`, not a `Range`.

Also, when adding the formula references, make sure you add single quotes around your `sourceFile`, e.g.:

```
Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = "'" & sourceFile & "Summary'!$F$2"
Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = "'" & sourceFile & "Summary'!$F$3"
Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = "'" & sourceFile & "Summary'!$B$10"
Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = "'" & sourceFile & "Summary'!$D$10"
                                      ^^^^^
```

Similarly for `dispersionRange` (notice the missing `=`):

```
dispersionRange = "'" & path & fileName & "Account'!R:R"
```

Finally, the last `.Formula` (for the "F" column) should be `.Value`, as `StDev` returns a Double. In addition, the function `StDev` doesn't take a range as String but a proper Range object, so try this instead:

```
Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = WorksheetFunction.StDev(Range(dispersionRange))
```

---

**UPDATE**

To avoid confusion, I've modified your code and I'm listing it below. Please note this is untested, as I don't have access to your workbook, but it should work.

```
Sub RefreshSourceData()

  Dim sourceFile, fileName As String, path As String
  Dim dispersionRange As String

  path = "U:\SPACE Info\Meeting Materials\Strategy Files\"
  fileName = "[" & ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, 1).Value & ".xls]"
  sourceFile = path & fileName
  dispersionRange = "'" & path & fileName & "Account'!R:R"

  Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = "='" & sourceFile & "Summary'!$F$2"
  Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = "='" & sourceFile & "Summary'!$F$3"
  Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = "='" & sourceFile & "Summary'!$B$10"
  Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = "='" & sourceFile & "Summary'!$D$10"

  Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = WorksheetFunction.StDev(Range(dispersionRange))

End Sub
```

Comment: Now I am receiving Run-Time Error 1004 "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed." It appears it does not like Range(dispersionRange)

Comment: @user2662565: I've updated my answer with a version of the final code that should work.